# Jquery jitter ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using this code but in Internet Explorer causes the header which follows the page scroll to act very jittery. Anyone know what problem could be?

```
var name = "#header";  
var menuYloc = 'null'; 

menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))           
$(window).scroll(function () {  
    var offset = menuYloc+$(window).scrollTop()+"px";  
    alert(offset);
       $(name).animate({'top':offset},500);  
});
```

Comment: could you provide a demo please

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to scroll the `#header` along with the scroll. It can be acheived by simple css.

```
#header
{
   position:fixed;
}
```